# When image select from Gallery 'Documents keeps stopping' error show

Tags: java, android

I am using this code for get image from gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CODE);
```

IMAGE_CODE is a constant int value